# Universal Static Libraryを作りなおしても変更が反映されない

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

githubで公開されているライブラリの動作を一部変更したく、
そのライブラリのxcodeprojを開きプログラムを変更し、
Static Libraryを作成しなおして自分のプログラムに追加し実行しました。

※ Static Libraryを扱ったのは今回が初めてです。。。

.a ファイルの作成日時が更新されているのも確認できていますが、
変更点が反映がされていないようです。

作成は[こちら](http://qiita.com/shintaness/items/ef04fd18547b10279524)の方法を参考にいたしました。

説明が乏しく申し訳ございません。
なにか原因がわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 「自分のプログラムに追加し実行しました」とありますが、具体的にはどうされたのでしょう？ その辺りを追記していただくと、問題の解決に繋がるかもしれません。もしかすると、作成し直したライブラリが本体のプログラムにリンクされていないのかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。具体的には、グラフを描画するライブラリのプログラムを一部変更し、上記でリンクしたサイトを参考にStatic Libraryを作り、生成されたxxxHeadersフォルダとxxx.aファイルを、追加したいプロジェクトにドラッグ＆ドロップで追加しています。そしてプロジェクトを実行してグラフ描画をしたところ、変更箇所が反映されていないようでした。変更箇所自体が間違ってる可能性もあるかなと、絶対に通る関数に変更を加えて追加しなおしてみましたが、それでも反映はされませんでした。

Comment: 可能性としては変更前のオリジナルのライブラリがどこかに残っていて、そちらの方がリンクされてしまっているのではないでしょうか。プロジェクトの設定にライブラリパス(リンクするライブラリを置くフォルダ)を指定する部分があるかと思いますので、その辺を確認してみると良いかもしれません。